# Firebase checking deployed files

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

When I run `firebase deploy` command, I would like to know which files are deployed.

I tried `firebase deploy --debug`, but I don't see any information about uploaded files.

```
[2018-05-25T09:48:26.423Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[2018-05-25T09:48:26.426Z] Command:       /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase deploy --debug
[2018-05-25T09:48:26.427Z] CLI Version:   3.18.4
[2018-05-25T09:48:26.427Z] Platform:      darwin
[2018-05-25T09:48:26.427Z] Node Version:  v9.2.0
[2018-05-25T09:48:26.428Z] Time:          Fri May 25 2018 11:48:26 GMT+0200 (CEST)
[2018-05-25T09:48:26.428Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------

[2018-05-25T09:48:26.439Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2018-05-25T09:48:26.440Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[2018-05-25T09:48:26.441Z] > refreshing access token with scopes: ["email","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","openid"]
[2018-05-25T09:48:26.442Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token  
 { refresh_token: '1/sNSNg7xxbzwVujBEzRAQ2eZHkEuT0d6A2jVVUGa-e9Jgrc8NASizU4RK7MEmNnov',
  client_id: '563584335869-fgrhgmd47bqnekij5i8b5pr03ho849e6.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  client_secret: 'j9iVZfS8kkCEFUPaAeJV0sAi',
  grant_type: 'refresh_token',
  scope: 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase openid' } 
 Fri May 25 2018 11:48:26 GMT+0200 (CEST)
[2018-05-25T09:48:26.585Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 cache-control=no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate, pragma=no-cache, expires=Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT, date=Fri, 25 May 2018 09:48:26 GMT, vary=X-Origin, Origin,Accept-Encoding, content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, x-content-type-options=nosniff, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-xss-protection=1; mode=block, server=GSE, alt-svc=hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303433; quic=51303432; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,42,41,39,35", accept-ranges=none, connection=close
[2018-05-25T09:48:26.593Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/test-table  

 Fri May 25 2018 11:48:26 GMT+0200 (CEST)
[2018-05-25T09:48:27.222Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 server=nginx, date=Fri, 25 May 2018 09:48:27 GMT, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, content-length=141, connection=close, x-content-type-options=nosniff, strict-transport-security=max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains, cache-control=no-cache, no-store
[2018-05-25T09:48:27.223Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/test-table/tokens  

 Fri May 25 2018 11:48:27 GMT+0200 (CEST)
[2018-05-25T09:48:27.777Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 server=nginx, date=Fri, 25 May 2018 09:48:27 GMT, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, content-length=274, connection=close, x-content-type-options=nosniff, strict-transport-security=max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains, cache-control=no-cache, no-store

=== Deploying to 'test-table'...

i  deploying hosting
i  hosting: preparing dist directory for upload...
[2018-05-25T09:48:28.900Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST PUT https://deploy.firebase.com/v1/hosting/test-table/uploads/-LDLglCdzpfzQK77Fbrb?fileCount=2&message=  

 Fri May 25 2018 11:48:28 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Uploading: [                                        ] 0%[2018-05-25T09:48:32.752Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 server=nginx, date=Fri, 25 May 2018 09:48:32 GMT, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, content-length=49, connection=close, access-control-allow-origin=*, access-control-allow-methods=GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, strict-transport-security=max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload, x-content-type-options=nosniff
[2018-05-25T09:48:32.753Z] [hosting] .tgz uploaded successfully, waiting for extraction
✔  hosting: 2 files uploaded successfully
[2018-05-25T09:48:33.642Z] [hosting] deploy completed after 5190ms
[2018-05-25T09:48:33.643Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://deploy.firebase.com/v1/projects/test-table/releases  
 { hosting: 
   { public: 'dist',
     ignore: [ 'firebase.json', '**/.*', '**/node_modules/**' ],
     version: '-LDLglCdzpfzQK77Fbrb',
     prefix: '-LDLglCdzpfzQK77Fbrb/',
     manifest: [] } } 
 Fri May 25 2018 11:48:33 GMT+0200 (CEST)
[2018-05-25T09:48:34.951Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 server=nginx, date=Fri, 25 May 2018 09:48:34 GMT, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, content-length=34, connection=close, access-control-allow-origin=*, access-control-allow-methods=GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, strict-transport-security=max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload, x-content-type-options=nosniff

✔  Deploy complete!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only information the Firebase CLI shows is:

> i  hosting: preparing dist directory for upload...

So this means that everything in your `dist` directory is deployed, and nothing else.

Since the files are uploaded as a single .tgz file, there is no progress report for individual files.